# C++ Speex to Flac wrapper/library

Tags: c++, wrapper, speex, flac

Application is using speex codec for transmitting audio to server. At server I need to decode speex to PCM (or something else ?) and then encode it using flac and send to Google Speech API. Is there any easy to use wrapper (or library) for speex/flac ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for gstreamer. I don't know too much about it but it can certainly handle FLAC and Speex according to [the plug-ins page](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html).